# How do I detect that a page is shown from coming back?

Tags: javascript, back-button

Our homepage is an empty page that detects the language of the browser and redirects the visitor automatically to his language page. The back button there (e.g. with Firefox) indeed leads back to our homepage, that unfortunately sends him to his language page again. The visitor seems to be caught on our page, the back button does not work any more.

So how can I detect on our homepage that it is executed by coming back? Then I would let Javascript press the back button again, instead of leading the visitor into the loop again.

The redirect on the homepage is done for every language. The homepage itself has no further content. The redirect is made by window.open:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  language = (navigator.userLanguage || navigator.language);
  language = language.substring(0,2); 
  switch (language) {
    case 'fr':
      window.open("fr/index.html",'_self');
      break;
    case 'de':
      window.open("de/index.html",'_self');
      break;
    default:
      window.open("en/index.html",'_self');
      break;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: had you try with any sample code?

Comment: You can cache language in `cookies` or `localStorage`

Comment: Well, ideally you'd be detecting the language on the server and respond with different content, or issue an HTTP 3xx redirect. Browsers handle this correctly. Redirecting via an interstitial Javascript page is the real problem.

Comment: you like to use javascript back button that work as browser back button.

Comment: Also, please clarify how that redirect works exactly. Does your homepage *always* redirect to a different page depending on the language, or is the homepage, say, English, and it redirects to a more specific language page if it detects the client's language, or what else is it doing exactly?

Comment: window.history.back(); use this java-script code.

Comment: I added information in the original question. Thanks for your answers. I fear there is no way to know that a page is executed from coming back?

Comment: Why would the user want to land on an empty page? I understand this is what you want to do.

Comment: Hello try-catch-finally, the empty first page (homepage) is just for redirection. The different language pages that are target of the redirection are not empty of corse!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used window.sessionStorage to know that the homepage was called the 2nd time (normally coming from the back button of one of the language pages):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  if (window.sessionStorage.getItem("goBack")=="True"){
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("goBack","False"); window.history.back();
  }
  else {
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("goBack","True");
    language = (navigator.userLanguage || navigator.language);
    language = language.substring(0,2);
    switch (language) {
      case 'fr':
        window.open("fr/index.html",'_self');
        break;
      case 'de':
        window.open("de/index.html",'_self');
        break;
      default:
        window.open("en/index.html",'_self');
        break;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Thank you all for your comments and answers. You led me to the right way!

Answer (score -2):

language independent code in js.

```
<script>
function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
}
</script>
```

> `<button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>`

Please Try this.